# Submit form from outside the component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the component `about.component.ts`

```
onSubmit(redirectAfter) {

    if (this.form.invalid) {
        this.notificationService.error(this.translateService.instant('fail'));
        return;
    }
....
```

Now in `about.html.ts` :

```
<user [form]="this.form"></user>
```

Now in the component with tag user `<user>` :

```
@Component({
selector: 'user',
templateUrl: './user.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() form?: FormGroup;
   validateAndClose() {
       this.form.onSubmit(false);
   }
```

So I want to call in the UserComponent the submit of the form that is in AboutComponent. I tried like this but not working. Have you an idea ? Thx in advance.

Comment: You can use `@Output()`, to emit a custom event that can be handled in the parent component.

Comment: You have two options here, use `@output` to emit the event or second if put the form fields in component and wrap it inside `<form>` and put the submit button outside the component but inside the `<form>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to @Output() a custom event from UserComponent which will trigger the submit in the AboutComponent

```
@Output() public submitEvent = new EventEmitter();
```

Then in AboutComponent template :

```
<user-component (submitEvent)="submit()"></user-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is using events.
You can create an output EventEmitter in your child component.
Parent react to that event.

```
<user-component (formSubmit)="parentSubmitFunc()"></user-component>
```

.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
   @Output() formSubmit = new EventEmitter<any>(); // <--

   validateAndClose() {
       [...]
       formsubmit.emit(anypayload); // <--
   }
```

Docs are [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Answer (score 0):

There's also an other way to access parent component methods without using `Output` event emitter. Which is by using `@Host`.

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form?: FormGroup;
  parentCmp: AboutComponent;
  constructor(@Host parentCmp: AboutComponent){
    this.parentCmp = parentCmp;
  }

  validateAndClose() {
    this.parentCmp.onSubmit()
  }
```

> **Limitation:** The parent method should not be private

[**Demo using @Host**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzwqde)